# Modular projects: Compile parent and child documents using separate custom classes

Tags: pdfpages, standalone, import, subfiles

I would like to compile a `main.tex` parent document using a custom class as well as child documents using different custom classes. I would like compilation of the parent document to automatically compile and correctly insert the child documents in place. How can I accomplish this without simply inserting a separate PDF file with `pdfpages`? The `standalone` and `subfiles` packages appear to nearly work, but custom classes must also be defined for the child documents.

Parent document:

```
\documentclass{acustomclass}

\begin{document}
    \childdocument
\end{document}
```

Child document:

```
\documentclass{anothercustomclass}

\begin{document}
    Hooray!
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does "appear to nearly work" mean? Can you describe the intended output and post some code of what you've already tried  ([minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) and describe, where it falls short, e.g. what should happen with the page numbers, etc.

Comment: It's a rather generic question in that I simply would like to include a child document that uses a custom `documentclass` in a main document.

Comment: The `combine` class may be of some help. Read the manual (`> texdoc combine`).

Comment: @AdamErickson I fear then, that your question (without problem description and expected output) is simply too generic

Comment: In addition to Peter's comment: There are several packages that could probably do what you want. Here is a list on CTAN: https://ctan.org/topic/subdocs

Comment: @DG Thank you! So, which of these packages allows one to compile and include LaTeX files using different document classes?

Comment: Since you don't specify how resulting conflicts should be resolved, I suggest you try them all and see for yourself, which fits your needs best. My guess: A `makefile`  (for automatically generating the parts) and `pdfpages` (to include them) will give you what you want.

Comment: @DG That is not very helpful. I've added the simplest possible example. I was also considering the `latexmkrc` + `pdfpages` approach, but was not sure how to do the makefile. Currently, I just use `pdfpages` manually, but this is not automated.

Comment: @PeterWilson Thank you! I see that you are the former package maintainer. I will give `combine` a shot.

Comment: @PeterWilson It looks like the `combine` package may indeed be the best answer. How can I use it with documents that have different class types on Overleaf?

Comment: @PeterWilson It simply errors out in my case, after following the documentation instructions, which also mention that it may error out when the classes are not the same.